# The data of $(++NF) covers the first column use awk

Tags: awk, z-score

I have a tsv file like this:

`$ head dd.tsv`

```
rs12184267       1       715265  C       T       0.035954        0.926915        -0.00125872     0.00152815      0.34

rs12184277      1       715367  A       G       0.036063        0.931148        -0.00133899     0.00152247      0.31

rs116801199     1       720381  G       T       0.0362940000000001      0.932145        -0.00120216     0.00151647      0.36

rs12565286      1       721290  G       C       0.036397        0.936321        -0.00126183     0.00151109      0.33

rs116720794     1       729632  C       T       0.036223        0.946579        -0.00107634     0.00150722      0.39
```

I want to add a new column about *Z score*, so I used command

`awk '{$(++NF)=$8/$9;print}' dd.tsv|head`

It returns the following results：

```
\-0.823689 1 715265 C T 0.035954 0.926915 -0.00125872 0.00152815 0.34

\-0.879485 1 715367 A G 0.036063 0.931148 -0.00133899 0.00152247 0.31

\-0.7927369 1 720381 G T 0.0362940000000001 0.932145 -0.00120216 0.00151647 0.36

\-0.835046 1 721290 G C 0.036397 0.936321 -0.00126183 0.00151109 0.33

\-0.7141234 1 729632 C T 0.036223 0.946579 -0.00107634 0.00150722 0.39
```

I don't understand why this happends. It seems that the data in the first column is covered by the data that should appear in the ++NF position.

It is worth mentioning that this code performs as expected on [awk REPL](https://awk.js.org/#), but in my machine, it does not work, I've checked version of awk and tried commands like `gawk`, `makw`, which have the resluts.

The version I am using is:

`$ awk -W version`

GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1) Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2020 Free Software Foundation.

I would appreciate it if you could give me some suggestions.

Comment: You probably have DOS line endings (\r\n). Since you are using GNU awk, try this: `awk -v RS="\r\n" ... [your code here]`

Comment: Unbelievable, this is the answer I want. This problem has been bothering me for almost an afternoon, thank you for your help!